# Prevent UITextField from changing width while typing

Tags: ios, uitextfield, nslayoutconstraint

I have the following layout :

[image: Screen Layout]

With the following constraints:

[image: First Item constraints]

[image: Second Item constraints]

[image: Third Item constraints]

The problem is the `UITextField` width changes it's with while typing:

[image: status 01]

[image: status 02]

[image: status 03]

Comment: It looks like your button width is set to `<= 47` -- that means you are telling auto-layout to go ahead and compress the width of the button (allow the textField width to grow) when needed. What happens if you change the button width to `= 47`?

Comment: Yes @DonMag It stop compressing the label but I need to set it <= because in some cases there is no text in the label and I need it to disappear.

Comment: Whoops... I just assumed that was a button. In any case, see my answer - that should take care of it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Leave your label's width constraint of `<= 47`, but change its

```
Horizontal Content Compression Resistance Priority` to `Required (1000)
```

[image]

This will prevent it from being **compressed** when there is too much text in the text field (the text field will scroll instead of expand).

Note that the `<= 47` constraint will truncate the label's text if needed. If you don't want that restriction, you can remove that width constraint entirely...